# Create a column based on row values in previous columns on excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that contains 8 columns and 88 rows. Each of the rows has either TRUE or FALSE value. I want another column to be created alongside where each of its 88 rows will have "TRUE" value if the same row of any of the previous columns also has "TRUE" value and "FALSE" otherwise.

In the context of the below table, I want the Fourth column to be created based on the row values in previous columns.

| First | Second | Third | Fourth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |

Please let me know if it's possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do some research and if you are still stuck ask the question and show what efforts you've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

`=OR(A2:D2)`

and copied down.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=IF(SUM(--(A2:C2=TRUE))>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Also this should work.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A2:C2,TRUE),TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]